# How comes Vue's shared state does not get updated without parseInt?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've noticed a minor issue in my code which I don't understand and I'm quite curious to find out why it's behaving like it is. I'm guessing its a general JavaScript thing rather than Vue.

Anyway, I am using a shared state to represent `Books`. However, when a book's `ready` attribute gets updated, the change is not reflected unless I use `parseInt(filterBook.ready)` when filtering the books to be displayed. By the way, `filterBook.ready` is an integer coming from a database. Does anyone know why this only works with `parseInt()`? Thanks.

This does not work:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="book in this.books.all.filter(filterBook => filterBook.ready)">
      <p v-text="book.name">
   </li>
</ul>
```

This works:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="book in this.books.all.filter(filterBook => parseInt(filterBook.ready))">
      <p v-text="book.name">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you inspect your data in debugger, is the data type of `book.ready` `Number` ?

Comment: Yes, it returns `number`. That's why I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only reasonable** explanation for this is that the `ready` is not a `number` but a `String`. I can't see the rest of the code, so I'm making assumptions here, but this is likely because your data is coming from a REST API as JSON object/array where the ready is numeric value, but in quotes.

if you check truthiness of a string `"0"`, it is true, which is why you need the parseInt.

you can validate that either using `typeof` in your component, or just see the data from the network panel in the dev tools.

example test:

```html
<ul>
   <li v-for="book in this.books.all">
      <p v-text="typeof(book.ready)">
   </li>
</ul>
```

---

As a side note, you should avoid functions in your template and prefer to use computed, this improves performance since the computed values get cached

```html
<ul>
   <li v-for="book in filteredBooks">
      <p v-text="book.name">
   </li>
</ul>
```

```js
computed:{
   filteredBooks: function(){
      return this.books.all.filter(filterBook => parseInt(filterBook.ready))
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using Axios to get the data from the back-end. However, I will keep playing around with it till I find out why. 

Wow, thanks so much for that tip. I will go back and refactor it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone else ends up here. I found out that the reason why I had to use `parseInt()`, it's because I was using Axios to get data from the back-end and [Axios returns a string for long data instead of an object](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1723).

When I was testing this by checking the `typeof` for `filterBook.ready`, it was returning `number` because the data I was getting from the back-end for the test was not that long.

Comment: That's interesting, I have not come across this case (bug?) before.